# Question involving Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Two linear transformations $T_1:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ and $T_2:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ are represented by the matrices $\mathbf{M}_1$ and $\mathbf{M}_2$ respectively, where
>    $$
>  \mathbf{M}_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 3 & 5 \\ 3 & -4 & 17 & 33 \\ 5 & -9 & 20 & 36 \\ 4 & -7 & 16 & 20 \\ \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{M}_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 0 & -3 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & -7 & 1 & -9 \\ 6 & -10 & 0 & -14 \\ \end{pmatrix}.
>  $$
>    The null spaces of $T_1$ and $T_2$ are denoted $K_1$ and $K_2$ respectively.  Find a basis for $K_1$ and a basis for $K_2$.
>
> It is given that $\mathbf{a}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$.  The vectors $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ are such that $\mathbf{M}_1\mathbf{x}_1=\mathbf{M}_1\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{M}_2\mathbf{x}_2=\mathbf{M}_2\mathbf{a}$.  Given that $\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2=\begin{pmatrix} p \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ q \end{pmatrix}$, find $p$ and $q$.

The first part poses no great difficulty. The bases are found easily enough. Basis for $K_1$ $(\{1\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{-1\})$; basis for $K_2$ $(\{1\}, \{2\}, \{1\}, \{-1\})$, where the curly brackets represent different rows. The second part has me at a loss. $P$ is supposed to be $4$ and $q$ to be $-4$. A proper explanation or any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones: nice typing, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $x_1-a$ is in the null space of $M_1$, and $x_2-a$ is in the null space of $M_2$. So they can be represented by the basis for $K_1$ and $K_2$, respectively. That gives you two parameters. The given condition of $x_1-x_2$ can solve the two parameters.